# Granting a role to a user using a dynamically created string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a fairly basic function in Oracle SQL developer which simply takes a user and role as parameters and runs GRANT role TO user (this function is being used in Oracle APEX).

```
create or replace FUNCTION GRANT_ROLE_TO(P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2, P_ROLE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER IS 
RESULT INTEGER; 
MY_SQL VARCHAR2(400);
ERROR_CODE NUMBER;
ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(255);

BEGIN
    
    MY_SQL := 'GRANT ' || P_ROLE || ' TO ' || P_USERNAME;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(MY_SQL);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE MY_SQL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('SQL WAS RUN');
    RETURN 1;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE; ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 255);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return 0;
   
END GRANT_ROLE_TO;
```

For example, I can run
`GRANT TESTING TO JDOE`
to give the TESTING role to JDOE. I confirmed this statement works. However, when I try to use
`SELECT GRANT_ROLE_TO('JDOE', 'TESTING') FROM DUAL`
it ouputs **ORA-01924: role 'TESTING' not granted or does not exist** and returns a 0 indicating the function did not work, even though I know and have verified TESTING exists and can be granted.
Does this have something to do with dynamically creating a GRANT string to be used with EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a permissions issue. A named proc/function will not honor any roles you might have giving you the ability to grant the role in question, whereas executing it ad-hoc does, so there's a privilege differential that is quite familiar in Oracle. Log in as `SYS` and give the function owner the `GRANT ANY ROLE` priv. Be aware that this essentially makes it a DBA-level account, but it sounds like that's already the case.

However, once you solve the permissions issue, you will have another problem. You cannot perform a DDL inside a function called by SQL, so calling it with `SELECT GRANT_ROLE_TO('JDOE', 'TESTING') FROM DUAL` will not work. You will get the error:

```
ORA-14552: cannot perform a DDL, commit or rollback inside a query or DML
```

Try executing the function normally, outside of SQL:

```
DECLARE 
  var_result integer;
BEGIN 
  var_result := GRANT_ROLE_TO('JDOE', 'TESTING');
  dbms_output.put_line(var_result);
END;
```

Comment: The account I'm using is both the function owner and already a DBA level account. Executing that block you provided still doesn't work, as the function still returns 0, so I believe it'd have to be a problem with something in the function itself.

Comment: My code will get you past the second bug you have. You're still stuck on the first one., which as I said is about permissions. Being the function owner doesn't help, and being a "DBA-level account" may not mean anything either. It's all about the actual grants possessed. Do you or don't you have the "GRANT ANY ROLE" system privilege *directly* granted to the function owner account?